# VoltDB Stored Procedures history

Tags: stored-procedures, voltdb

I have many stored procedures running in Volt and it seems like 1 of them is causing spikes in CPU every now and then but I don't know which one.

Is there somewhere I can see the history of all the stored procedures that ran so that I could pinpoint the problematic one based on the time it occurred?

I have tried turning the Command Logging on but it's a binary file so I have no way of reading it.

My next option is to log from inside the stored procedures but I prefer to keep this option as a last resort because it will require some extra developing/deploying and it won't be relevant for internal procedures.

Is there any way to log/somehow see when stored procedures ran?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a log of every transaction in VoltDB that a user can review. The command log is not meant to be readable and only includes writes. However, there are some tools you can use to identify poorly performing or long-running procedures.

You can call "exec @Statistics PROCEDUREPROFILE 0;" to get a summary of all the procedures that have been executed, including the number of invocations and the average execution time in nanoseconds. If one particular procedure is the problem, it may stick out.

You can also grep the volt.log file for the phrase "is taking a long time", which is a message printed when a procedure or SQL statement takes longer than 1 second to execute.

Also, there is a script in the tools subdirectory called watch_performance.py, which can be used to monitor the performance. It is similar to calling "exec @Statistics PROCEDUREPROFILE 0;" at regular intervals, except there are some columns gathered from additional @Statistics selectors, and the output is formatted for readability. "./watch_performance.py -h" will output help and usage information. For example, you might run this during a performance load to get a picture of the workload. Or, you might run it over a longer period of time, perhaps at less granular intervals, to see the fluctuations in the workload over time.

Disclosure: I work for VoltDB